# How to this with a DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in which I need to implement two features and I'm a bit blocked on how to implement them.

First, I want to add a row at the end of the grid with the totals of the other rows and I want this row to be fixed so it does not get sorted when the others are.

Second, it's a grid with a lot of columns but they can be grouped into different aspects of the data, so I would like to expand and compress some groups of columns to allow the grid to be viewed on the screen. I would like to do something like putting an expander on a set of columns.

Any help would be great. Thanks for your time!

Comment: this will not be done in a few lines of code - this is IMHO a major endevor. Maybe 3rd party vendors like Telerik or Devexpress have some good controls up there sleves and I would go and look there before building something like this from scratch...

Comment: Well, at least I thought that the total feature wouldn't be so hard. What do you think? I would like to avoid using 3rd party controls if possible.

Answer (score 2):

For the first point you need to work with the footer row, putting totals or summaries in the footer row will allow you to always see it with no sort or scroll issue.

For the second point, if I got it right, being able to hide a bunch of columns and show them again does not sound trivial or easy without quite some code.

Personally whenever a grid needs certain amount of customization I'd like go for commercial grids like DevExpress or Telerik, in any .NET platform like WPF, WinForms ASP.NET or SliverLight those controls pay off very well and very soon considering the rich feature set and possibilities without your precious time spent on grids but actually keeping your focus on the real business.

see online demos from DevExpress or Telerik for their cool WPF grids.

Comment: I didn't know of a footer row. Looks like what I'm looking for. Thanks, I will check it.